# Использование Context в других классах

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, context

У меня есть диалоговое окно, в котором я использую список. Требуется считать этот список с документа.

Есть метод `changeGroup`, где массив с документа будет меняться. Требуется передать этот массив в диалоговое окно `DialogGroupSelection`. Но при использовании метода `group` из класса `Book` требуется передать `Context`. И тут и есть проблема, я не понимаю, что именно надо передать.

Чтобы я не пробовала всегда одна и та же ошибка:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference.

При этом, если вызывать метод `group` в `MainActivity`  в `onCreate`, то ошибок нет.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    DialogFragment dlg;
    Book book = new Book();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Создаем переменную типа Book
    String[] data = book.group(this); // Так работает нормально

    dlg = new DialogGroupSelection();
    dlg.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg");

    }

public String[] changeGroup(){
   String[] dat = book.group(); // Какой Context передавать сюда?
   return dat;
}

public class Book{
    // В переменную записываем имя файла
    String text = "list.xls";
    InputStream fis;

    public String[] group(Context myContext){
        try {
            //Открываем нужный документ
            AssetManager myAsset = myContext.getAssets();
            fis = myAsset.open(text);

            // Создаем книгу
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int number_sheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets()-1;

            //Создаем массив из перых ячеек каждого листа
            String[] group = new String[number_sheets];
            for(int count_list = 0; count_list<number_sheets; count_list++) {
                group[count_list] = wb.getSheetAt(count_list).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            }
            return group;
        }
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

}

И диалоговое окно DialogGroupSelection.
Код:

```
public class DialogGroupSelection extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

MainActivity mainact = new MainActivity();
String[] list = mainact.changeGroup();
//String[] list = mainact.book.group(); Можно ли обращаться напрямую? И какой Context тогда использовать?
int i=1;
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    adb.setTitle("Выберите свою группу")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ваша группа: " + list[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // or return them to the component that opened the dialog

                }
            });
    return adb.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в MainActivity так

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
DialogFragment dlg;
Book book = new Book();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Создаем переменную типа Book
    String[] data = book.group(this); // Так работает нормально

    dlg = new DialogGroupSelection();
    dlg.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg");

}

public String[] changeGroup(){
    String[] dat = book.group(this); 
    return dat;
}

public class Book{
    // В переменную записываем имя файла
    String text = "list.xls";
    InputStream fis;

    public String[] group(Context myContext){
        try {
            //Открываем нужный документ
            AssetManager myAsset = myContext.getAssets();
            fis = myAsset.open(text);

            // Создаем книгу
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int number_sheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets()-1;

            //Создаем массив из перых ячеек каждого листа
            String[] group = new String[number_sheets];
            for(int count_list = 0; count_list<number_sheets; count_list++) {
                group[count_list] = wb.getSheetAt(count_list).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            }
            return group;
        }
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

В классе для диалога так, getActivity() вернет вам Activity, в котором был показан ваш диалог, т.е. MainActivity

```
public class DialogGroupSelection extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

int i=1;
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String[] list = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeGroup();
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    adb.setTitle("Выберите свою группу")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ваша группа: " + list[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // or return them to the component that opened the dialog

                }
            });
    return adb.create();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы меня просто спасли :)

Answer (score 3):

Так же и передавай `this` или так `MainActivity.this`, а вот в `Dialog` вот так

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity()
```

делать не надо там же есть метод `getActivity()`, а вообще можно все это сделать через интерфейс.

Comment: Если пишу `MainActivity.this` ошибка все равно остается, а приложение автоматически закрывается.